# Why Rails doesn't include the Javascript files at the bottom of the HTML page by default?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I read [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) that it is better to include Javascript files at the bottom of the HTML page.

Why Ruby on Rails doesn't do so by default ?

Comment: I don't have an answer for why RoR doesn't do that, but I think it's a false pretense anyway.  I just tested in Chrome and Firefox and both download multiple scripts at the same time.  I tested a page of mine that loads four different javascript files, they're all declared at the top at the same time, and they're all requested from the server 78ms after initial request (there's a 302 redirect in there).  So I don't think it makes a difference anymore. 

Older browsers may still do this, though, like IE6 or something.  But still, it shouldn't really matter unless you've got JS files over 1MB.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this article is about 233 weeks (~ 4.5 year) old. It might have been true during that time, that javascripts blocked parallel downloads, but it isn't anymore. Even though the article is this old, it still has some valid tips which help to improve your websites loading speed and performance.

Comment: An issue (2012-04-11) has been submitted on Rails project webpage:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5815/ titled "Move javascript to bottom of the page". This also leads to this pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5921 "Add a comment encouraging developers to move js to bottom" (2012-04-24).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess that Rails includes your `application.js` in the `<head>` by default because it assumes you'll be minimizing things via the asset pipeline. There's no need to worry about where your script is included if it's a single external file being loaded in parallel by a single HTTP request.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizing things via the asset pipeline" ?

Comment: @Misha Rails 3.1 will concatenate and compress all your JS assets into a single file via the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).